# Spark DataFrame groupBy and aggregation is throwing NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: exception, apache-spark, dataframe

I am doing the following query on Spark DataFrame

```
  input
   .select("id")
   .groupBy("id")
    .agg(count("*").as("count"))
```

I am getting java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException

```
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.getBytes(UTF8String.java:234)
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.toString(UTF8String.java:827)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateProcessRow$1.apply(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator$$anonfun$generateProcessRow$1.apply(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregationIterator.processInputs(TungstenAggregationIterator.scala:533)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work

```
input.groupBy("id").count()
```

Comment: The query works in most of the cases but fails and throws exception only with some input data. Here is my actual query input
   .select("id","quantity")
   .groupBy("id")
    .agg(sum("quantity"))